# Reshape with Keras. Error: total size of new array must be unchanged

Tags: keras, reshape

I am trying to build a keras model with a Reshape layer. I want to go from shape (batch_size, 50, 2) to (new_batch_size, 10, 2).

The thing is, the transformation works fine when I independently do:

```
X_sub = x_train.reshape((-1, 10, 2))
```

However, I get error when I add a Reshape layer.

```
new_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(10,2), input_shape=(50,2)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
```

I have tried different inputs that don't give error, however the output shape is not the one desired. Why is that happening?